# Is it possible to have more than one condition to suppress a row in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I'm trying to put together a report to track our record reviews. In order to not have duplicates I have a condition to suppress a row if it's a duplicate

```
{review.clientNo} = Previous({review.clientNo})
```

and it works fine.

For who knows reasons one of our employees who does not do record reviews has access to two fields that relate to the tables of the record reviews and they keep checking off these fields even though they don't need to. So even if that particular record was not reviewed it still shows up on the report because two fields within it have entries. Until we can undo that we still want to run the reports. So I want to have two conditions to suppress either the one i have typed or the one in which only those fields are present and all others a null

This is what I have so far but crystal reports isn't liking it.

```
{review.clientNo} = Previous({review.clientNo})     
or isnull( {review.initialDate} + {review.followUp} + 
{review.code47A} +{review.clientSales} + {review.totalSales} + 
{review.salesQuantity} +{review.clientSatisfaction} + {review.clientAddress} 
+ {review.clientEmail} +{review.clientNumber} + {review.orderNumber} + 
{review.orderTrack} + {review.orderFill} + {review.orderAmount} +
{review.orderSize} +{review.deliveryMethod} + {review.salesDate} + {review.orderDate})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula called suppression

```
if 
    {review.clientNo} = Previous({review.clientNo}     
    or 
    (
    isnull({review.initialDate})
    AND isnull({review.followUp})
    AND isnull({review.code47A})
    AND isnull({review.clientSales})
    AND isnull({review.totalSales})
    AND isnull({review.salesQuantity})
    AND isnull({review.clientSatisfaction})
    AND isnull({review.clientAddress})
    AND isnull({review.clientEmail})
    AND isnull({review.clientNumber})
    AND isnull({review.orderNumber})
    AND isnull({review.orderTrack})
    AND isnull({review.orderFill})
    AND isnull({review.orderAmount})
    AND isnull({review.orderSize})
    AND isnull({review.deliveryMethod})
    AND isnull({review.salesDate})
    AND isnull({review.orderDate})
    ) 
then 1 else 0
```

in the suppression for your header and footer try this

```
sum({@suppression},{fieldgroupedon}) =0
```

You could also, by the way, now change your detail record suppression to just

```
{@suppression} = 1
```

I hope I got all that right!

Comment: I have one follow up question: Would it be possible to suppress the group header and the group footer if the second condition is met? The tricky part is that not all group headers would be suppressed because they still have rows that are not null

Comment: should be.. did you try it? You can suppress the header with separate criteria than you used in detail.

Comment: I did the problem was that it suppressed group headers that had data as well. I guess is there a way to suppress the group header if every row is suppressed?

Comment: Place the formula above in a formula .. whiups I hit enter too early .. more to come

Comment: I'm getting an error in the field suppression telling me @suppression cannot be summarized

Comment: ACK! I forgot about the previous function you are using. Thats why it is not letting you summarize.  OK I have a plate full today but will try and get back to this to help with a better solution if noone else comes up with one.

Comment: Sorry I havent gotten back to this.  My real job has been quite demanding lately. Before we try to solve this though I have a question. Do you need to return records for any other reason if ALL of those fields are null? If not, could you put a formula simialr to 
    isnull({review.initialDate})= false
    AND isnull({review.followUp}) = false etc.. in your record selection?

Comment: I don't need to return records if everything is null

Comment: then lets go back to the beginning... add that code (just the null parts) in your record selection and dont bring them into the report at all.

Comment: ok done. and when you say don't bring them into the report, do you mean the formula or the records that are in the formula?